# What is the q.catch() equivalent for parse promises?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In the Q-promise library, if there is a random problem like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'blah' of undefined` then it can be handled via the `Q.catch()` block.

But in Parse-promise library, if there is such a problem inside a `then()` block, I currently see no way of handling it other than putting a try/catch inside every single `then()` block!

Am I missing something? What is the q.catch() equivalent for parse promises?

Or are such errors simply impossible to capture without a try/catch block in every `then()` block?

`.then(function(data)){
        try{
            // do something with data that might throw an exception/error
        }
        catch(exception){
            return Parse.Promose.error(exception);
        }
    })`

Comment: The more I research, I fear there may not be a real alternative yet. I filed a bug with Parse+Facebook, if this matters to you, may be you could chime in to show your support there: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1511145499127274/

Answer (score 1):

As per [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), the `.then()` function in all Promises/A+ compatible libraries (including the Parse-promise library) takes two callbacks - `onFulfilled` and a `onRejected`.  If the first argument ie. `onFulfilled` throws an exception, the promise is rejected and the second argument will be called.

In other words, your example can be rewritten:

`.then(function (data) {
      // do something with data that might throw an exception/error
    }, function (exception) {
      // handle the exception
    })`

In addition, Parse-promises (like many promise libraries) provides [additional APIs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html) to make this neater.  Specifically, you can use .fail() to wire up callbacks to get called if the promise is rejected.

Comment: Tried it and `.fail()` doesn't work to capture errors that we could if we placed try/catch explicitly in the `then` block ... given Parse's implementation. I'm not asking about rejections per say, I'm askinh about handling the corner case like runtime errors with Parse.